# form not sending data in ajax.serialize when form contents are updated via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing problem when using javscript to update inner html of form. I want to dynamically add input type with same name in form and then send this form data via jquery ajax serialize.
Eg.

```js
function addinput()
{
  //update form html to add following 
  
  <input type="text" value="1" name="addtext" />
  <input type="text" value="2" name="addtext" />
  <input type="text" value="3" name="addtext" />
  <input type="text" value="4" name="addtext" />
  <input type="text" value="5" name="addtext" />
}
  
function initiate()
{
 
 document.myform.action="initiateMultipleReceiptReceiptAction.action?next=0"; 

var formdata=$('form[name$="myform"]').serialize();   
    
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:addinput()">Click to add more</a>
<form id="myform" action="initiate();">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

now the problem is that formdata is not showing $addtext value

Comment: Where are you adding these inputs to the form? Have a look at [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/). You would want to do something like this `$("#myform").append('<input type="text" value="1" name="addtext" />')` to add the `input` element to your form in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Due to some css issue it has to be added inside div tag

Comment: Why are you using `$('form[name$="myform"]')` if your `<form>` has no `name` attribute? Then, I don't think an `action` attribute can contain javascript. See [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/form)

Comment: @Burn its just to show working ignore the syntax. instead of id consider it as name attibute

Comment: @Harvi Non-sense. We can't help you if you don't show us a valid example. Anyway, a fact remains: you can't use javascript code as value of `action` attribute (except denials!)